# Angular not scoped method

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I am wondering, does all the methods declared in an angular controller have to be added to the scope?

is it possible to call a controller method from ng-click="myMethod()", with my method not delared as a $scope.myMethod = => , but @myMethod = =>

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `as propertyName` feature of `ng-controller` to get close:

Declare your controller like this: `ng-controller="some.controller.name as controllerNameInScope"`. And then do `ng-click="controllerNameInScope.myMethod()"`.

See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngController